# how to eliminate silcrow (paragraph) sign in doxygen for python

Tags: python, doxygen

I'm writing code in `Python` and documenting it in `Doxygen`. Why am I using `Doxygen` instead of `docstrings`? It is project requirement.

For some reason when I document `Python` code every method has a [section/silcrow sign, §](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign),  next to it. Here is the image:

[image]

Is there a way to eliminate it?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Create a HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET and place in this:

```
.permalink
{
        display: none;
}
```

Comment: I guess what I was wondering is why the section sign is displayed at all? I used doxygen to generate documentation for `C/C++` and never saw it there. Why is it being generated for `python`?

Comment: It is present for overloaded functions